# QT-Box-Editor.exe v1.10 and v1.09 are infected with virus, any clue where else I can download a virus free exe?

Tags: tesseract

I tried to download the above exe file from this site,
https://github.com/zdenop/qt-box-editor/downloads

however, both ver 1.10 and 1.09 are infected with virus when checking against virustotal.com

For ver 1.10, VirusTotal returned :

1. MaxSecure Trojan.Malware.300983.susgen
2. McAfee    Artemis!5C87D43589E7
3. McAfee-GW-Edition
   BehavesLike.Win32.Trojan.fc
4. SecureAge APEX Malicious

I googled, however, failed to get a virus free version of the exe at other sites.

Can anyone help ?
I don't know how to build an exe from the source file, if need be, where can I get instruction set to build the exe ? like linking all the needed dependencies with the correct version, what software required to be installed to compile the source code.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/lian/msfs2020-go/issues/14  or https://www.reddit.com/r/antivirus/comments/qo9vus/is_this_safe_and_false_positive_from_virustotal/  use reliable (paid) antivirus

Comment: @user898678, does it mean that github.com downloads is always virus free, no need to do additional checking? just new to this virus checking, thanks

Comment: No. But totalvirus is not reliable antivirus. It is known for marking opensource projects as virus-infected.

Comment: @user898678, ok, for this QT-Box-editor.exe, I will ignore the 3 warnings from Virustotal

Comment: QT-Box-editor was created for tesseract 3. I doubt it will be helpful for the recent version of tesseract (v5).